# How do i force shut down on a computer without on off button

Tags: shutdown

I have a chromebook, I just installed Uberstudent(based on ubuntu 14.04) on it and when I tried to reboot it after installing, it doesn't shut down.

It just says

> SQUASHFS error: Unable to read metadata cache entry [a6a58c76]
>
> SQUASHFS error: Unable to read directory block [a6a58c76:196]

over and over and I can't write anything. I removed the USB while it was shutting down, so maybe thats something.

Anyway, I want to force shut down but acer 720p chromebook doesn't have a shut down key, it uses F12 as a shut down key which doesn't work since i installed linux.

So, how do i force shut down?

Comment: Take the battery out of the laptop

Comment: i think its welded in

Comment: An unrelated note: Holding just Refresh and poking the Power button hard-resets the machine without entering Recovery. That's occasionally useful, but use it with care - it doesn't sync the disk or shut down politely, so there's a nonzero chance of trashing the contents of your stateful partition. -- https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c720-chromebook

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if UberStudent has this feature since I never used this distro before but try the following in the `command line` to force a shutdown:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This other command will force a reboot:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Comment: Nothing happens when i write anything. i got somewhere when i pressed alt+F7. now i can write things but nothing happens when i press enter after each line, it just changes row

Comment: Hmmm that is odd, so you can't do any basic commands like `ls`, `cd`,etc..?

Comment: no. the two rows that i wrote in the question comes when i press the shut down button

Comment: Just looking at that error message may point to a number of reasons why this is occurring. Take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors

Comment: Thanks, but those didn't help since nothing happened when i pressed enter except for new line.

Comment: I didn't expect it to provide a solution but an idea as to why you are experiencing the problems you are..

Comment: I'll just have to run out the battery i guess

Comment: sudo shutdown now

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway, I want to force shut down but acer 720p chromebook doesn't have a shut down key, it uses F12 as a shut down key which doesn't work since i installed linux.

1. The power key is the power key. I just checked with my N22 booting Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB HDD. The N22 keyboard is not supported (USB keyboards work), but when I press the power button at the login screen I'm getting the shutdown or reboot options. If I would press the power button for 4 seconds or a bit longer it would power down via ACPI, I had to do that before, so I know that works despite of what function is mapped.
2. Realize that there are different keyboard mappings. Just because you use a distro which is unaware of chromebook hardware doesn't mean that the power key becomes the F12 key or some other misguided interpretation of what this key is or isn't.

Comment: t'internet says to hold _8_ seconds for most chromebooks

Comment: Sounds interesting, any reference? It could be that the 8 seconds refer to when you are in Chrome OS where it slowly fades to the lockscreen when you hold the power button and shutsdown after that when you hold it further, but that feels quicker than 8 seconds.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromebook-central/mKxNRrBJGuE/0eOdsdXqLbcJ 
+ https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/2l0njz/how_do_i_restart_my_c720_while_frozen/clqfv24/